# how to stop the Sharepoint workflow and trigger it when it reaches date

Tags: workflow

Workflow will be triggered when it reaches the particular date. I don't want workflow to be triggered when particular item is changed. How can i achieve that

Answer (score 0):

Inside your workflow set that Date Column you have, and when the Actual date = Date in Column then the Workflow will start --> Set your workflow to be trigged manually --> last part in this process is to bind your workflow with "Retention Policy" Then set "Retetion Policy's TimerJob to run one time each day

Answer (score 0):

Workflow are meant to implement a Workflow : a communication, action between some users and some operations.
For your case you need a Timer Job not a workflow.
You have to implement w workflow who runs every day/hour(depending on your need) it would check all the item of your list, and when the date is dued you execute your operation.